# How to set XAML property via a function call?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a simple page with a rectangle, an ellipse, two sliders and a textblock.

The two slider controls (via binding) the height and width of the rectangle.

I would like to set the width and height of the ellipse based on the smallest value of the rectangles dimensions.  The XAML code looks like this:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="App16.MyUserControl1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App16"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="400"
d:DesignWidth="400"
x:Name="MyRoot">   

<Grid Background="Black">

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Rectangle Name="rect" Fill="Yellow" 
               Width="{Binding ElementName=rectX,Path=Value}" 
               Height="{Binding ElementName=rectY,Path=Value}" Grid.Column="0"/>

    <Ellipse Fill="Yellow" 
             Width="{Binding ElementName=MyRoot,Path=SampleFunction}" 
             Height="{Binding ElementName=MyRoot,Path=SampleFunction}" Grid.Column="1" />

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">                       
        <Slider Name="rectX" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Minimum="100" Maximum="200" Value="150" />
        <Slider Name="rectY" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Minimum="100" Maximum="200" Value="150" />
        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding ElementName=MyRoot, Path=SampleFunction}" />
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

The code behind looks like this:

```
public Double SampleFunction {             
        get { return (rect.Width <= rect.Height ? rect.Width : rect.Height); }
    }
```

In its current state, the rectangle resizes properly according to the value in the sliders, but "SampleFunction" is never called after the page is loaded.

Of course I could do this with the "RESIZED" event, but I wondering if this was possible without doing that.

Any suggestions?  When the user adjust the slider control I would like to see the rectangle and ellipse change size.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your `SampleFunction`needs to be renamed (it's a property, not a function).

And to make it work for DataBinding it needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

In addition, the internal logic should probably be base on `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight`.

Comment: Since the source of the binding is a control (UserControl) - it would actually need to be a dependency property. INotifyPropertyChanged does not belong in controls.Then again that would be too much work and I would rather simply handle a MyRoot.SizeChanged event to make the calculations if they were actually necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Henk's suggestion with my comment would make it work, but actually for your scenario you can remove the bindings altogether and simply set

```
<Ellipse
    Fill="Yellow"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    Stretch="Uniform" />
```